# Conditional form fields in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus, lotus-formula

I try to build an advanced form in Lotus Notes. Some fields should hide in condition to the state of other fields.

I can hide one field by defining a formula for this. But the problem is I have to first save the document, close it and reopen it to see the fields are hidden.

I want that the field is hiding while the UI doc is in edit mode when I change the state of fields.

Thank you!

Best regards
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set option "Refresh fields on keyword change" to recalculate the hidden formulas of other fields.

This option is avaliable for fields of type

- Dialog list
- Checkbox
- Radio button
- Combobox

Answer (score 2):

*Try to use one of the following commands:*

[ViewRefreshFields](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_VIEWREFRESHFIELDS.html)

```
@Command([ViewRefreshFields])
```

or

[RefreshHideFormulas](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REFRESHHIDEFORMULAS.html)

```
@Command( [RefreshHideFormulas] )
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use various approaches to achieve this. If you use some sort of select-fields like Radiobutton or Checkbox you can use the field option "Refresh on keyword change" to recalculate the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Call notesUIDocument.RefreshHideFormulas` but beware of it's greedy resource consumption on large forms.

[Link on IBM Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_REFRESHHIDEFORMULAS_METHOD.html)